# Use mutex or not in a concurrent reading

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am programming in C++ in Linux and I am using pthreads library. I am using mutex to protect some shared variables but I am not sure if in this specific case it is necessary the use of mutex.

I have 3 threads. The shared variable is a string (global variable).

Thread1 changes it's value and afterwards, thread2 and thread3 read it's value and store in another string.

In this case, the string's value is only modified by one thread. Is still necessary the use of mutex to protect a shared variable in a concurrent read by two threads?

Comment: You need a mutex whenever there's at least one thread modifying the object. The only situation when you don't need it is when *everyone* is only reading.

Comment: But Threads 2 and 3 only read the string's value when Thread1 has already modified it's value.

Comment: If you can ensure that thread 1 has finished modifying the string before any of the others try to read it, then you're in the situation where everyone reads: no mutex needed.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks!

Comment: I have another question. If we had the same situation but 3 threads can (1 write and 2 read) access the variable concurrently. And the variable would be bool instead of a string. Will be any problem?

Comment: Within the bounds of the standard, yes there would: unsynchronized simultaneous accesses of which at least one is a write are known as race conditions, and trigger undefined behaviour. Some platforms are able to perform lock-free atomic operations on certain simple data types, but you cannot rely on the standard anymore. To deal with this, you'd use `std::atomic<bool>`, which will be transformed into the optimal operation for your platform, degrading into a mutex if nothing else is available.

Comment: Many thanks! it has been very useful! :)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. In essence I want to check a variable in thread 2 and 3 (a bool) to see wether the threads are supposed to stop themselves and resolve or not. I check the variable in a loop so as soon as it reads anything other than 0 or false the thread will stop itself. The bool variable can only be modified in thread 1 and will only be done if all threads are supposed to be stopped. So I have to  lock and unlock the mutex in every thread if I want to check that variable? That's gonna lead to problems as I could have 1000s of threads (it's for a proxy). It will slow down a lot

Answer (score 4):

"Thread1 changes it's value and afterwards ..." -- if "afterwards" means that the other threads are **created** after the change, there's no need for a mutex; thread creation synchronizes memory. If it means anything else then you need some form of synchronization, in part because "afterwards" in different threads is meaningless without synchronization.

Comment: As you have said, ("afterwards" in different threads is meaningless without synchronization) the synchronization has been made using mutex. So then, there is no need to protect them. Thank you!

Comment: @JulenUranga - a mutex does not guarantee that something happens **after** something else. All it does is ensure that they don't happen at the same time (loosely speaking). If you need to have a thread read a value after the value has been written by another thread you need some way to communicate that the value has already been written.

Answer (score 1):

What you should use is a [shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) (get it from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) if you don't want to use C++14/17) (for C++14 there's a [shared_timed_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) that you could use). Then, you do a [shared_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock) if you want to read the string, and you do a [unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) if you want to write on it.

If two shared locks meet, they don't collide and they don't block, but a shared lock and a unique lock collide and one of the locks blocks until the other finishes.

Comment: I am using pthreads library and I would not like to change it. Even so, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @JulenUranga Actually whether or not you're using pthreads is irrelevant. The locks don't care!

Comment: I know! But I want to maintain the structure and continue the project with the same "functions" related with threads :)

Comment: @JulenUranga I understand. That's not a bad thing at all. But keep the `shared_mutex` solution as a last resort if you don't find any other solution. Besides, it's part of the standard library, so you don't have to add additional special libraries for it. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using pthreads, you can use a `pthread_rwlock_t`.

For updating the object, it would be [locked using `pthread_rwlock_wrlock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_wrlock.html) to get a write lock; all readers would access the object only after obtaining a shared read lock [with `pthread_rwlock_rdlock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_rdlock.html).  Since the write lock is exclusive, and the read lock is shared, you'd get the behavior you desire.

An example of the use of `pthread_rwlock_t` read/write locks can be found at http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/using_readwrite_locks.htm.

A good summary of the available calls for use on a `pthread_rwlock_t` lock can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032u/index.html.  I've reproduced the table listing the operations:

```
Operation 

Initialize a read-write lock                   "pthread_rwlock_init(3THR)"

Read lock on read-write lock                   "pthread_rwlock_rdlock(3THR)"

Read lock with a nonblocking read-write lock   "pthread_rwlock_tryrdlock(3THR)"

Write lock on read-write lock                  "pthread_rwlock_wrlock(3THR)"

Write lock with a nonblocking read-write lock  "pthread_rwlock_trywrlock(3THR)"

Unlock a read-write lock                       "pthread_rwlock_unlock(3THR)"

Destroy a read-write lock                      "pthread_rwlock_destroy(3THR)"
```