# How to share a global object between threads?

Tags: c++, class, c++98, mbed

I have created a class, which has many public functions, some which write data and some that only read data.

It's required that I do this within 3 threads, I have no other option.

I know if I accessed a shared resource just to read, then I don't have to protect, but I don't know if it is any different when I am using a function to read a private variable of the shared resource.

E.g. I am trying to do...

```
globalObject.readColour();
```

which is a function that reads the colour of the global object.

Does it mean that I have to secure the thread at this point, or is it okay to just read the value without any risks?

I'm working on mbed, which supports c and c++98.

Comment: If you're only reading, you are ok. You just have to make sure that you don't try to read while another thread tries to write. This is often refered to as read/write locks. The idea is that you can let as many threads as you want read at the same time, but as soon as one thread needs to write, you must stop all the reading before writing. [std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) could be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use mutex or not in a concurrent reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651592/use-mutex-or-not-in-a-concurrent-reading)

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651592/use-mutex-or-not-in-a-concurrent-reading)

If all your threads will only read the variable then you don't need mutex (or similar), but if any thread performs a writing operation you should use mutex.

Comment: FYI, here is the Mutex documentation for Mbed OS 5: [Mutex](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.11/apis/mutex.html).